# Zoomable area in d3 v4 not working

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I am trying to follow this https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0xece4k/17/'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Plotting a Trendline with D3.js</title>
<style>
    .line {
        stroke: blue;
        fill:none;
        stroke-width: 3;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .text-label {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

</style>
<div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var height = 300;
    var width = 600;
    var margin = {top: 10, right:20, bottom: 50, left: 40};

    // formatters for axis and labels
    var rateFormat = d3.format("0.1f");
 var trendDataArr = [
     {
     date: "2017-01-29",
     value: 87.1
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-06",
     value: 88
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-13",
     value: 86.8
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-20",
     value: 86.8
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-27",
     value: 87.1
        },
     {
     date: "2017-03-05",
     value: 85.8
     },
     {
     date: "2017-03-12",
     value: 85.5
     },
        {
        date: "2017-03-19",
        value: 87.1
        },
        {
        date: "2017-03-26",
        value: 88
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-02",
        value: 87.4
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-09",
        value: 86.8
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-16",
        value: 87.1
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-23",
        value: 87.4
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-30",
        value: 85.8
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-07",
        value: 86.5
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-14",
        value: 87.1
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-21",
        value: 86.9
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-28",
        value: 87.7
        },
        {
        date: "2017-06-04",
        value: 87.8
        }
];



var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var svg = d3.select('#container')
        .append("svg")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .attr("width", 1000 + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .append("g");


        svg.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "zoom")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                    .call(zoom);


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis");


         function getDate(d) {
             return moment(d["date"],"YYYY-MM-DD").toDate();
         }

             function removeDuplicates(xLabels){
                var result = [];
                             xLabels.forEach(function(item) {
                                     if(result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                                             result.push(item);
                                     }
                             return result;
                     });
             }


      var minDate = getDate(trendDataArr[0]),
      maxDate = getDate(trendDataArr[trendDataArr.length-1]);


      var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
           // .rangeBands([margin.left, width-100], .1);
                   .domain([minDate, maxDate])
                     .range([margin.left, width])
                    // .nice(trendDataArr.length);

      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d %b %y'));

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
        var xLabels = trendDataArr.map(function (d) { return getDate(d); });

        xScale.domain(d3.extent(xLabels));
        yScale.domain([Math.round(d3.min(trendDataArr, function(d) { return parseFloat(d['value']); }))-5, Math.round(d3.max(trendDataArr, function(d) { return parseFloat(d['value']); }))+5]);

        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return xScale(getDate(d)); })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(d['value']); })
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal);


   svg.append("path")
     .datum(trendDataArr)
     .attr('fill','none')
         .attr("d", line(trendDataArr.filter(function(d) {

                                     return d;
      }
                 )
               )
             )

             .attr('stroke', "steelblue")
             .attr('stroke-width', 2);


        svg.select(".x.axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+5) + ")")
            .call(xAxis.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d %b %y")))
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor","end")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-45) ";
            });

        svg.select(".y.axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis.tickFormat(rateFormat));

        // chart title
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", (width + (margin.left + margin.right) )/ 2 -200)
            .attr("y", 0 + margin.top -20)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "16px")
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .text("Zoomable chart");

            //y axis  label
        svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Rate");

        function zoomed() {
                var t = d3.event.transform;
            xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(xScale).domain());
        }

</script>
</body>
```

Could someone help me with the zooming in/out on the axis so that I can drill into each day or zoom out to years?

Comment: Can you please fix you fiddle? It is throwing Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined error

Comment: Fixed the fiddle.I had it with the resources but had not saved it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work:
here is the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q0xece4k/17/

```
var height = 300;
    var width = 600;
    var margin = {top: 10, right:20, bottom: 50, left: 40};

    // formatters for axis and labels
    var rateFormat = d3.format("0.1f");
 var trendDataArr = [
     {
     date: "2017-01-29",
     value: 87.1
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-06",
     value: 88
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-13",
     value: 86.8
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-20",
     value: 86.8
     },
     {
     date: "2017-02-27",
     value: 87.1
        },
     {
     date: "2017-03-05",
     value: 85.8
     },
     {
     date: "2017-03-12",
     value: 85.5
     },
        {
        date: "2017-03-19",
        value: 87.1
        },
        {
        date: "2017-03-26",
        value: 88
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-02",
        value: 87.4
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-09",
        value: 86.8
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-16",
        value: 87.1
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-23",
        value: 87.4
        },
        {
        date: "2017-04-30",
        value: 85.8
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-07",
        value: 86.5
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-14",
        value: 87.1
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-21",
        value: 86.9
        },
        {
        date: "2017-05-28",
        value: 87.7
        },
        {
        date: "2017-06-04",
        value: 87.8
        }
];



var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var svg = d3.select('#container')
        .append("svg")
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .attr("width", 1000 + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .append("g");


        svg.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "zoom")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                    .call(zoom);


    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis");


         function getDate(d) {
             return moment(d["date"],"YYYY-MM-DD").toDate();
         }

             function removeDuplicates(xLabels){
                var result = [];
                             xLabels.forEach(function(item) {
                                     if(result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                                             result.push(item);
                                     }
                             return result;
                     });
             }


      var minDate = getDate(trendDataArr[0]),
      maxDate = getDate(trendDataArr[trendDataArr.length-1]);


      var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
           // .rangeBands([margin.left, width-100], .1);
                   .domain([minDate, maxDate])
                     .range([margin.left, width])
                    // .nice(trendDataArr.length);

      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
                            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d %b %y'));

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
        var xLabels = trendDataArr.map(function (d) { return getDate(d); });

        xScale.domain(d3.extent(xLabels));
        yScale.domain([Math.round(d3.min(trendDataArr, function(d) { return parseFloat(d['value']); }))-5, Math.round(d3.max(trendDataArr, function(d) { return parseFloat(d['value']); }))+5]);

        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return xScale(getDate(d)); })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(d['value']); })
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal);


   svg.append("path")
     .datum(trendDataArr)
     .attr('fill','none')
         .attr("d", line(trendDataArr.filter(function(d) {

                                     return d;
      }
                 )
               )
             )

             .attr('stroke', "steelblue")
             .attr('stroke-width', 2);


        svg.select(".x.axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+5) + ")")
            .call(xAxis.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d %b %y")))
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor","end")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-45) ";
            });

        svg.select(".y.axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis.tickFormat(rateFormat));

        // chart title
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", (width + (margin.left + margin.right) )/ 2 -200)
            .attr("y", 0 + margin.top -20)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "16px")
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .text("Zoomable chart");

            //y axis  label
        svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Rate");

        function zoomed() {
                var t = d3.event.transform;
            xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(xScale).domain());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call xAxis again.

```
function zoomed() {
  console.info('zoom called');
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(xScale).domain());
  svg.select(".x.axis")
 .call(xAxis.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d %b %y")));
}
```

This is not the complete solution as it just zooms xAxis and not the plot but it might help you in zooming the plot too.

Or you might want to refer: https://bl.ocks.org/deristnochda/1ffe16ccf8bed2035ea5091ab9bb53fb